# Set rules for net connected to specific component in Altium

Tags: altium

I'm using Altium 17.1. I'm trying to set a clearance rule for my PCB. Some of my components have tight pads and thus I need to set a low value for that component. I set the pad to pad clearance with `InComponent` query to skip pad to pad check. Now I'm trying to define a clearance rule for all nets connected to a specific component. I don't want to set individual rule for nets one by one. I tried to use this query but didn't work:

> InNetClass('All Nets')  and InComponent('U5')

Actually, I'm trying to use `Autoroute` But I want to set low clearance for specific components that their pad is very tight compared to other parts.
EDIT:
I'm trying to say that the green clearance is fine and for the red circle is violate. Suppose clearance between these pair nets is the same.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably put these nets in a net class.

But PCB cost tends to be driven by the tightest tolerance on the board. You probably don't save very much by allowing loose tolerances elsewhere, if you have tight tolerances on part of the board. So really the simplest solution might be to just set your overall design rules for the tighter tolerance.